# How to reference a shape by name and what else can be used in .Select?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I use MS Excel 2007

My question is in two parts

I have a form option button called "Option1"

1. How do I refer to that button in other macros?
   I know that I can select it using: 
   ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option1").Select

but I really only need to use something like

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option1")
Doing this throws an error in VBA.

2.
Taking ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option1").Select

Is there a list or resource that shows what else can be used where the .Select part is?

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using `Form Control OPTION BUTTON` then the different command should be used.**

**Below are few examples:**

```
ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("Option Button 1").Select

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 1").ControlFormat.Value = Xlon

Range("A1")=Activesheet.OptionButtons("Option Button 1").value

ActiveSheet.OptionButtons("Option Button 1").LinkedCell = "Sheet1!$A$1"
```

**or**

```
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 1").ControlFormat.LinkedCell = "Sheet1!$A$1"
```

*To Run Macro on Option Button Click:*

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 1").OLEFormat.Object.OnAction = "Module1.MyMAcro"
```